# Notepad++ Highlight Occurrences Where Words Contain Symbol

Tags: notepad++

The occurrences highlighter didn't work if what I'm selecting contain symbol.

This is working: "myvar"
This not working: "$myvar"

How can I set this? Thank ou.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very similar question was asked/answered [here (Catching a PHP variable using double click in Notepad ++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092725/catching-a-php-variable-using-double-click-in-notepad) (I'd mark this as duplicate if I could).

To answer your question though: it does not appear that it is possible in Notepad++.

However, if you don't mind a few extra clicks you can still highlight all of the occurrences by "marking" those words. Do the following to accomplish this:

1. Highlight the text you want to Mark (in your case, '$myvar')
2. Press Ctrl-F to open the Find dialogue box
3. Go to the Mark tab
4. At this point, you can now click 'Mark All'
5. Now all of the matches will be highlighted!

[image]

You can also access this functionality by selecting the text you want to Mark and going to Search->Mark All. The benefit of doing it this way is you can now Mark multiple different words with different styles quite easily. You can also clear all Marks by style by going to Search->Unmark All

[image]

Here is how multiple, different styled, Marked selections look:

[image]

Comment: Yes its similar problem to mine. Just from different perspective. Thx for pointing out. It save my time from searching for solution.